# Read lines of a text file into an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, file, text

I would like to display a new quote randomly every time someone launch the app.In order to do that I was thinking of using a text file containing all the quotes, one at each line.

I would like to know in android studio where should I put my text file and then how can I read this text file and put each line into an array?

I found this code that looks to make the job but it doesn't seems to work:

```
// set up variables
String fileName = "MyFriends.txt";
String line;
ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();

//Read the lines of text into an ArrayList

try {
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
if (!input.ready()) {
    throw new IOException()
}
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    aList.add(line);
}
input.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Thanks

SOLUTION:
This page helps a lot : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

```
String[] quotes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quotes_array);
Random randomGenerator = new Random(); 
//Construct a new Random number generator
int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(quotes.length);
fact = quotes[randomNumber];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty non-android way of thinking of things.

Consider using `res/values/strings.xml` to store your quotes, then read a random one from there by using `getResources().getStringArray(R.string.quotes)`, then generating a random integer between 0 and the size of that array.

Bonus of using resources - you can use the same identifiers, but change the quotes themselves based on region.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it in the assets directory. If you do so, the way you access the file also will change. Google to see how to read a file from assets.